# How can we share GPU over a network

Tags: gpu, sharing

I have been thinking for a long time about sharing GPU over a computer network. Suppose there is a computer/VM having a GPU and another Computer /Vm  B not having a GPU. How can Computer B utilize the GPU of A over a network?

I know that it is very hard to do as GPU is hardware but we can actually share CPU over the network. Is it possible to do it...**In Kubernetes we can share GPU between two pods in the same node ([Proof](https://blog.ml6.eu/a-guide-to-gpu-sharing-on-top-of-kubernetes-6097935ababf)) but not across different pods in different Nodes**.

Please help me to find a way to share GPU between **different nodes/machines.**

[image]

Comment: Question too broad. How could anyone answer this? In Kubernetes, a node represents a physical computing device, so both pods are on the same physical machine as the GPU, nothing is done over the network

Comment: When you say "share CPU over the network" what is actually happening is that A sends data to B, B performs operations with that data on its CPU, then B sends back results to A via the network. You could write software that would do the same with GPUs, but I'm not sure what you are intending to achieve with that?

Comment: Some malware does that. Implement a client/server setup, the server A doing the GPU requests of B and return the result.

Comment: @UnholySheep By doing GPU sharing we could actually save lots of amount of money .and cut down costs .....GPUs are very expensive ...this is what I want to achieve inside the cars running lots of machine learning workload nowadays especially.... self-driving ones running ADAS .

Comment: I'm not an expert on cars, but I highly doubt that they are using consumer level desktop GPUs. Or that they are doing their machine learning on the fly. You'd usually train ML models "offline" and execute the trained model during runtime

Answer (score 0):

[JuiceLabs](https://www.juicelabs.co/) has a GPU-over-IP product with a [community version](https://github.com/Juice-Labs/Juice-Labs/) that may suit your needs.